# WinUi3 Expander class in not found

Tags: c#, .net, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I'm developing a simple windows 10 utility app using C# & WinUi 3. So the main component of my app is the Expander component/control. My problem is that the Expander control is not found. It's not found in the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls` namespace.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

I followed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/set-up-your-development-environment?tabs=vs-2022-17-1-a%2Cvs-2022-17-1-b) step by step but it didn't work.

Installed Packages are:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the message I got:

[image]

Comment: WinUI3 classes are not in the Windows.* namespace but in the Microsoft.* ones (yeah, it can be confusing): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/expander https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.expander?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1

Comment: Thanks for you response. i checked the namespace Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls; as well but I couldn't find the Expander class.

Comment: I don't know how you installed WinUI3 but it's definitely there: Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Expander

Comment: As I mentioned I installed WinUI3 through the Visual Studio 2019 Installer. following the official documentation.

Comment: Judging by your screenshots, you have *not* followed the documentation.

Comment: @mm8 can you explain how ? please.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've installed Visual Studio 2022 and it's finally working.